# Send 'jq' output to a file using subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, jq

I am not entirely sure how jq works here with subprocess so there is a misunderstanding but I am trying to get the extact format from using jq on the command line ( `jq > file.json`) with subprocess. This is what I have but the following produces an empty file.

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filePath))
open(filePath, 'a').close()

call(["bw", "list", "--session", session_key, \
    "collections", "|", "jq", ".", ">", filePath])
```

I have also tried

```
with open(filePath, "w+") as output:
        call(["bw", "list", "--session", session_key, \
         "collections", "|", "jq", "."], stdout=output)
```

But this produces a string instead of the actual formatting of jq. Is there a way for me to obtain the stdout jq on the commandline into a file using python?

Comment: `|` and `>` to configure pipes and redirect output are features offered by your shell. `subprocess.call()` runs `bw` *directly*, with no intermediary shell process. So either handle connecting process pipes and and output file yourself in Python or use `shell=True` and pass in a single string.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how this can be done?

Comment: See the duplicate links on your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a shell, you need two subprocesses.

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filePath))
dst = open(filePath, 'a')

p0 = Popen(["bw", "list", "--session", session_key, "collections"], 
    stdout=PIPE, check=True)
p1 = Popen(["jq", "."], stdout=dst, stdin=p0.stdout, check=True)
p1.communicate()
dst.close()
```

This is almost literally lifted from the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) There is a [`pipes`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pipes.html) module in the standard library which somewhat simplifies this, though it is arguably clunky; thus, there are also several third-party replacements.

On the other hand, perhaps this is one of those situations where you can defend `shell=True`.

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filePath))
dst = open(filePath, 'a')
subprocess.run("""
    bw list --session '{}' collections |
    jq .""".format(session_key),
    stdout=dst, shell=True, check=True)
dst.close()
```

On the third hand, if you really want a shell script, why are you writing Python?

Comment: The first solution worked perfect, thanks.

Comment: What is the `check= true` doing here?

Comment: It causes an exception to be raised if the command fails.